# How to say "one" as in "anybody in general."

Tags: words, phrase-requests

In English, it is not uncommon to come across a sentence such as "One's outlook on life depends on one's personal experience." In this case, "one" is referring to people in general. So the above sentence could just as easily be written as "A person's outlook on life depends on that person's experience."

My question is, how close of an approximation to the above use of the word "one" is the word「人」such as in「人の人生観は（その人の？）個人的な経験によって違う」? Are there cases where the word「人」is better replaced by some other word (or nothing at all)?

Answer (score 3):

I think the Japanese sentence.

> 「人の人生観は（その人の？）個人的な経験によって違う」

was very accurately translated to your

> "One's outlook on life depends on one's personal experience."

This is kind of the difference of experience how much you used be to the use of the Japanese 人.

Here, 人, **in Japanese too** denotes **every each person in general in the entire world**